# OperationalError at /admin/login/ even after making migrations

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-migrations

I have made migrations still i am getting this error . I have tried deleting the database and making it again. I have tried making migrations again and again but problem is still there.

OperationalError at /admin/login/
no such table: auth_user

Note
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate

i have used both

Comment: You should not only *make* migrations, but also *migrate* the database...

Comment: I have migrated

Comment: Did you add `'auth'` to the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting?

Comment: i just added but problem is same

Comment: did you make migrations and migrated *after* adding the `auth` app?

Comment: yes but no changed detected in migration

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem one more thing database has a table named "auth_user" but still django says it is not found

Comment: do you use two or more databases (defined in the `DATABASE` setting)?

Comment: I have two databases on my server but i have defined one in settings

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the migrations folder but don't delete **init**.py file. After this, run the commands:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```